# Reuse jquery in another control

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code inside a ASP.Net MVC 3 razor view

```
var uriArticulos = '@Url.Action("ObtenerArticulos", "Articulo")';
$("#descripcionArticuloEditandoTextBox").autocomplete({
    source: uriArticulos,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#idArticuloEditandoTextBox").val(ui.item.Id);
        $("#unitarioArticuloEditandoLabel").text(ui.item.Unitario);
    }
});
```

I need to use this autocomplete in a lot of places.
How can I reuse it in another control in other views in the same project whithout copy & paste?

I'm trying this code, but nothing happens

```
jquery.autoComplete.js

(function ($) {
    $.fn.articuloAutocomplete = function () {

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var uriArticulos = '@Url.Action("ObtenerArticulos", "Articulo")';
            $this.autocomplete({
                source: uriArticulos,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#idArticuloEditandoTextBox").val(ui.item.Id);
                    $("#unitarioArticuloEditandoLabel").text(ui.item.Unitario);
                }
            });

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

And I'm calling it with

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.articuloAutocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#descripcionArticuloEditandoTextBox").articuloAutocomplete();
.
.
.
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You might consider making an autocomplete [editortemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I need to do in jquery